# TabbedPage - Call method when certain Tab is active

Tags: c#, android, c, xaml, xamarin

I have a scenario where I want to call a method when the user of the app navigates to a certain tab of the TabbedPage.

Example: If I navigate to tab no. 3 of my TabbedPage, a certain method shall be called.

How do I achieve that?
By default all tabs of the TabbedPage are loaded when I start the app.

I am writing in Xamarin - C#.

Best regards!

Comment: Maybe [OnCurrentPageChanged()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.multipage-1.oncurrentpagechanged?view=xamarin-forms) helps you?

Answer (score 1):

There are two sample ways to achieve that.

**One** is using `OnAppearing` method inside the needed item of tab page.

For example, the tab no. 3 of TabbedPage is **ItemsPage**, then its **ItemsPage.xaml.cs** code as follows:

public partial class ItemsPage : ContentPage
{

```
    public ItemsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        // Call your needed method here 
    }
}
```

**The another way** is using `OnCurrentPageChanged` methond inside the **tabbedpage.xaml.cs**.

For example, the code as follows:

public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
public MainPage()
{
InitializeComponent();
}

```
    protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();
        if(CurrentPage.Title == "tab no. 3 title")
        {
          // call your needed method
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(CurrentPage.Title);
    }

}
```